# unable to start zookeeper server

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I was doing setup zookeeper and while setting zookeeper server I am getting below out put. Server is not starting.

```
.10\bin>call "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\b
:43,637 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@134] - Reading configuration
from: C:\zookeeper-3.4.10
:43,651 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
:43,651 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
:43,651 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
:43,654 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@113] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config,
:43,790 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@134] - Reading configuration from: C:\zookeeper-3.4.10
:43,792 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@96] - Starting server
:43,824 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.10-39d3a4f2
:43,824 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=P4A-508SD1Q.dir.svc.acc
:43,824 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_111
:43,824 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
:43,824 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\j
:43,825 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=C:\zookeeper-3.4.
:43,825 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=C:\Program File
:43,826 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\SHASHI~1.
:43,826 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
:43,829 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Windows 7
:43,830 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
:43,830 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=6.1
:43,830 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=shashibhusan.mohanta
:43,831 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=C:\Users\shashibhusan.m
:43,832 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin
:43,852 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@829] - tickTime set to 2000
:43,855 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@838] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
:43,856 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@847] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
:44,194 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

I am not understanding what is the maxSessionTimeout set to -1 what does that mean and how to fix please help.

Answer (score 1):

That means, you haven't specifically set those values and zookeeper will be using default values for `maxSessionTimeout` and `minSessionTimeout` which are 20 and 2 times the `tickTime` respectively.

Read the [zookeeper minimum configuration docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.1/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_minimumConfiguration).